# use CCSprite in uiview

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have an Objective-C project. In the project, I want to use some CCAction on the image(UIImage). So, I think I need to change all UIImage into CCSprite.
  I have a function which add image to view for all images in the project:

```
UIImage* firstImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];    
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:firstImage];
[targetView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
return imageView;
```

At this point, I don't know how to do addSubview on CCSprite. As I know, in cocos2d, only one CCGLView is using.
  Is there any hints? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful Notes for you:

« You can add one CCSprite to other CCSprite by using addChild method.

« Creating CCSprite from UIImage:

```
CCTexture2D *tex = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:uiImage] autorelease];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];
```

« Creating UIImage from CCSprite:

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromSprite :(CCSprite *)sprite
{
    int tx = sprite.contentSize.width;
    int ty = sprite.contentSize.height;

    CCRenderTexture *renderer   = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:tx height:ty];

    sprite.anchorPoint  = CGPointZero;

    [renderer begin];
    [sprite visit];
    [renderer end];

    return [renderer getUIImage];
}
//call syntax
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)node;
UIImage *p = [self imageFromSprite:sprite]
```

Comment: is it possible to do it like this?
(1), convert UIImage to CCSprite
(2), runAction on CCSprite
(3), update CCSprite properties to UIImage
e.g. CCMove, CCScale, update co-ordinate and scale of UIImage

Comment: Answer is yes..nothing is impossible...all you need to do is learn first :)